# Evaluating a surface fit (sfit) using mixed scalar/vector inputs in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

Consider the following 3D surface:

[image: plot of the sfit output]

I have fitted an equation to this surface using `cftool` (MATLAB 2014a) after constructing the appropriate `meshgrid` matrices (`XX`,`YY`,`ZZ` such that `ZZ=f(XX,YY)`). At some later point I wanted to evaluate the fit over a "line", e.g. `sfit_eq(3:0.01:5,600)` but MATLAB refused to give me a result, claiming that there's a dimension mismatch between the inputs (`Error while trying to evaluate FITTYPE function obj: Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.`).

While it can be easily resolved using `repmat` or `meshgrid`, I'm wondering - **is there a way to evaluate the `sfit` directly using inputs of inconsistent dimensions** (in other words - let *it* bother with the data gridding if such is required)**?**

Comment: have you tried sfit_eq(3:0.01:5,600*ones(201,1))?  However, If the function gives you error because inconsistent dimensions that LITERALY means that you can not use inconsistent dimensions...

Comment: @Ander - that's the same as `repmat`\ `meshgrid`. Either it's really impossible, or I am missing some flag, or perhaps a wrapper function or something along those lines...

Comment: I think its imposible. dont try to cheat on matlab! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to revisit this problem today (this time, in MATLAB 2015a).

My initial thought was to get the desired result using a mixture of `bsxfun` and `@feval` which I didn't seem to get quite right. But then I noticed that **in this version of MATLAB it *just works* the way I wanted it to**.

I guess this problem may be solved by simply upgrading to a newer version of MATLAB.